# Modifying jQuery $.ajax() success method during request

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the web app I am working on there is potential for very long running ajax queries.

I'm using jQuery's $.ajax method to do something like:

```
this._xhr = jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/path/to/service",
    data: "name=value",
    success: function(data, message){
        // handle a success
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Is there a way to modify the success callback after this._xhr.readyState = 2 (loaded) and before this._xhr.readyState = 4 (completed)

I tried modifying this._xhr.onreadystatechange but found that jQuery does not define onreadystatechange.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Maybe there is a solution that doesn't involve monkeying with the `success` function in the middle of a request

Comment: The success method does some expensive processing, however the user can perform additional actions in the UI during the long running ajax requests which really cancel the request.  If those actions occur I was going to change the success method of the running query to display a simple message once it does finally complete, rather than do all the processing that is no longer needed.  I could use the abort() method, which may be the proper way, but I was curious if it was possible to modify the success function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `abort` method sounds like the best option to me.

I don't know much about the `ajax` method internals, but I can think of a few ways to do what you want. Both involve global state and would break if it's possible for your user to send a second request before the first has finished, so I'm not sure I recommend them.

First, you could keep a reference to the method that does your success work, and change it:

```
MySuccessMethod = function(d, m) { /* handle a success */ };

this._xhr = jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/path/to/service",
    data: "name=value",
    success: function(data, message){ MySuccessMethod(data, message); },
    dataType: "json"
});


// later...
// user cancels request, so change the success method
MySuccessMethod = function(d, m) { /*print a simple message*/ }
```

Alternatively, you could just put all the logic in the one success method, and use a global flag to determine what to do:

```
success: function(data, message){
    if (RequestHasBeenCancelled) {
        //display a simple message
    }
    else {
        // handle a success
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I've gone ahead and used `abort` for now, but I like the thinking in your first suggestion, I could take that idea and apply something similar to my code and actually without involving global state.  Thanks Again.